# Need regular expression for 4-12 alphanumeric characters or special characters (~!@$%&*_+) at least one letter, no spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Please see below examples which needs to be satisfied with the regular expression.

Rule : 4-12 alphanumeric characters or special characters (~!@$%&*_+)  at least one letter, no spaces

```
test                  ---------This is Valid
test@2                ---------This is Valid 
test2                 ---------This is Valid
2222                  ---------This is NOT Valid
2222@                 ---------This is NOT Valid 
@2222                 ---------This is NOT Valid
test user2            ---------This is NOT Valid
testUser              ---------This is Valid
testUser@2            ---------This is Valid 
testUser2             ---------This is Valid
testUser.2            ---------This is NOT Valid
```

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: A tool like this helps you test as you go: http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
/(?! )(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z~!@$%&*_+]{4,12}/g
```

[***DEMO***](http://regex101.com/r/wY9bX3)